# What's wrong with the layout XAML

Tags: xaml, layout, winrt-xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

Tell me why when working with the application code, the whole area is allocated listbox, rather than a specific line listboxItem placed in a table row?

```
<ListBox x:Name="menu" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionChanged="Changed">
       <Grid>
          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
             <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
             <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
             <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <ListBoxItem Name="Main" Grid.Row="0">
             <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock FontSize="20" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" 
                           Text="&#xE710;"/>
                <TextBlock FontSize="17" Text="Add" Margin="10 0 0 0"/>
             </StackPanel>
          </ListBoxItem>
         <ListBoxItem Name="Details" Grid.Row="1">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
               <TextBlock FontSize="20" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" 
                          Text="&#xE71B;"/>
               <TextBlock FontSize="17" Text="Add Link" Margin="10 0 0 0"/>
             </StackPanel>
          </ListBoxItem>
       </Grid>
    </ListBox>
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve exactly ?

Comment: I would like to place on a split panel controls in its various parts - the top and bottom. I did not want to use the radio buttons for this purpose. I decided to give them as change the style of the buttons is difficult for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you populate the `ListBox` control by adding `UIElement` items directly, the `UIElement` are added to the `Items` collection.

For your scenario, you actually only added one `Grid` to the Items collection of `ListBox`, and then in this `Grid`, you added another two `ListBoxItem`, the `ListBoxItem`s were not directly added to the Items collection, but to the `Grid` control of one Item, the `Grid` control here is more like the `root` control of this Item. This is the reason of your problem:

> the whole area is allocated listbox, rather than a specific line listboxItem placed in a table row?

So, base on your code and your question, I think what you need is possibly like this:

```
<ListBox x:Name="menu" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionChanged="Changed">
    <ListBoxItem Name="Main">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock FontSize="20" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                   Text="&#xE710;" />
            <TextBlock FontSize="17" Text="Add" Margin="10 0 0 0" />
        </StackPanel>
    </ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem Name="Details" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock FontSize="20" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                  Text="&#xE71B;" />
            <TextBlock FontSize="17" Text="Add Link" Margin="10 0 0 0" />
        </StackPanel>
    </ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```

And I'm not sure what is your third `RowDefinition` is for, if you have questions about this, you can leave a comment. It's better to describe the layout you want to achieve.